# How Can I Make Automation Test Using Selenium C# for a Web app Built with AngularJS?

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium, automation

I’m using Selenium C# for Automation testing, and Its not working with applications built with AngularJs as they are client side.Can any one tell me what’s my options to make automation test for applications built with AngularJS? I want something which can be used with Selenium C# at Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like maybe basic selenium isn't the right tool. Protractor is built on top of WebDriverJS and is commonly used for this scenario:

http://www.protractortest.org/#/

It seems there is some support for C# bindings out there for protractor, but I'm not sure how dedicated that support is.

One example is the Protractor nuget package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Protractor/

Answer (score 0):

**Protractor for .NET is an end to end test framework for Angular applications**

**Protractor for .NET is built on top of Selenium WebDriver C# binding.**

**Get it from NuGet!**

> Install-Package Protractor

Reference: [Protractor net Home page](https://github.com/bbaia/protractor-net)

[Good basic learning youtube video about Protractor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLEydfdd-Ms)